# is there a functiojn to break a text and keep it in the next line inside a container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, break

Container(
height: 100,
width: 320,
child: Text(
domaindesc,
softWrap: true,
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
style: GoogleFonts.roboto(textStyle: ktextstyle),
),
),

Answer (score 0):

If you mean creating a new line in the same text paragraph? add this '\n' where you want a new line to start.

Also if you want to change the fontstyle for different parts of the text (e.g. on a new line, for example) you can use TextSpan. Example borrowed from the Flutter docs with '\n' new line inserted to illustrate:

```
return Container(
              child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              text: 'Hello \n ',
              style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
              children: const <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                    text: 'bold',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
              ],
            ),
          ));
```